# Erro ao realizar commit no Projeto. Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, git

Ao realizar commit em meu projeto surgiu o seguinte erro anexado abaixo, não consigo identificar o que está causando isto. Preciso de ajuda. Já desinstalei o git instalei novamente atualizei o visual studio, porem o erro persiste.

[image]

Comment: *"já tentei solucionar de diversas formas mas nenhuma surgiu efeito"* deveria citar o que já tentou na sua pergunta assim não sugerimos coisas que já tentou, fica mais fácil de analisar

Comment: Desculpe, me expressei errado, já corrigi.

Comment: tranquilo, mas a ideia é que coloque mesmo na pergunta qualquer coisa que já tenha tentado ai ajudar a entender melhor o que está acontecendo

Comment: de qualquer forma esse erro geralmente acontece quando está adicionando ao git arquivos que não deveriam ir, pode resolver isso adicionando esses arquivos a um arquivo `.gitignore`, por exemplo essa pasta `.vs` não deveria ir

Comment: veja se isso resolve e posso colocar uma resposta mais detalhada, mas na pasta raiz do seu projeto deve ter um arquivo `.gitignore`, se não tiver inclua um, é um arquivo de texto que deve ter somente esse "nome", e incluir nele a linha ".vs/" para não fazer o commit dessa pasta

Comment: Okay tentarei, mas se você responder mais detalhadamente será de grande ajuda

Comment: Consegui commitar somente o arquivo, porém as alterações não @RicardoPontual